# LWC Button to Open Create Record Page - So Complicated?

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button

New to LWC...in visualforce, all I need to create a button that opens the create record page is:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
      <apex:commandButton value="New Use Case" action="/a1A/e?retURL={!Opportunity.id}&oppid={!Opportunity.id}" />
      <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="saveButton" />
      <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" />                             
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

In LWC this seems much more difficult, am I missing something? I just want a "New" button at the top of my lightning card, is there no way to just specify a URL? I found this, but it involves a whole new JS class, and I'm not sure how to do that in conjunction with the JS I already have. Create a whole new file?

Many thanks

HTML

```
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_medium" label="New" onclick={???}></lightning-button>

    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">  

        <div if:true={records.data}>  

            <template for:each={records.data} for:item="rec">    

                <div key={rec.Id} class="slds-box">  

                    <lightning-record-form record-id={rec.Id}   
                                           object-api-name={objectName}   
                                           layout-type="Full"   
                                           mode="view"  
                                           columns="4"> 
                                            
                    </lightning-record-form>  

                </div>  
                  
            </template>  

        </div>  

    </div>  

</lightning-card>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';  
import fetchRecords from '@salesforce/apex/RelatedListController.fetchRecords';
  
  
export default class RelatedList extends LightningElement {  
  
    @api objectName;  
    @api fieldName;  
    @api fieldValue;  
    @api parentFieldAPIName;  
    @api recordId;  
    @api strTitle;  
    @api filterType;  
    @api operator;  
    get vals() {  
        return this.recordId + ',' + this.objectName + ',' +   
               this.parentFieldAPIName + ',' + this.fieldName + ',' +   
               this.fieldValue + ',' + this.filterType + ',' + this.operator;  
    }  
      
    @wire(fetchRecords, { listValues: '$vals' })  
    records;  
  
}
```

EDIT:
I have made the updates below, works now.

```
<template>  
      
    <lightning-card title={strTitle} icon-name="standard:record"> 

        <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_medium" label="NewMix" onclick={navigateToNew}></lightning-button>

        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">  
  
            <div if:true={records.data}>  
  
                <template for:each={records.data} for:item="rec">    
  
                    <div key={rec.Id} class="slds-box">  
  
                        <lightning-record-form record-id={rec.Id}   
                                               object-api-name={objectName}   
                                               layout-type="Full"   
                                               mode="view"  
                                               columns="3"> 
                                                
                        </lightning-record-form>  
  
                    </div>  
                      
                </template>  
  
            </div>  
  
        </div>  
  
    </lightning-card>  
      
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';  
    import fetchRecords from '@salesforce/apex/RelatedListController.fetchRecords';
    import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation'; 
      
    export default class RelatedList extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {   
      
        @api objectName;  
        @api fieldName;  
        @api fieldValue;  
        @api parentFieldAPIName;  
        @api recordId;  
        @api strTitle;  
        @api filterType;  
        @api operator;  
        get vals() {  
            return this.recordId + ',' + this.objectName + ',' +   
                   this.parentFieldAPIName + ',' + this.fieldName + ',' +   
                   this.fieldValue + ',' + this.filterType + ',' + this.operator;  
        }  
          
        @wire(fetchRecords, { listValues: '$vals' })  
        records;  
    
        navigateToNew() {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: 'POC_Use_Case__c',
                    actionName: 'new'
                }                    
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are your default values coming from? If you open the browser's console I suspect you will see an error when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, removing state: {defaultFieldValues: defaultValues} got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LWC we have [navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) mixins.

All you need is below changes to your lwc component, Extend a navigation mixin and implement it for new button nav

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class ComponentClass extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    navigateToNewOpportunity() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'Opportunity',
            actionName: 'new'
        }
    });
}
}
```

---

HTML Template changes

```
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_medium" label="New" onclick={navigateToNewOpportunity}></lightning-button>
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I add that JS to the JS that I already have?

Comment: yes precisely. You add to the same js file you have. Notice you have to also extend your js class to use NavigationMixin. Essentially change the first line and add the code i showed

Comment: Yes but how? I have changed the code to what you see below the original description, but the button is doing nothing when clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure to change
extend LightningElement to extend NavigationMixin(LightningElement)
without which the NavigationMixin would not work.
[Docs Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_default)